# JetBrains Academy ASCII cow draw issue

Tags: java, ascii, println

I am beginner Java programmer, I'm taking JetBrains Academy course and the task is to output a cow in ASCII:

**The Goal:**

1. Expand your program so that it requests the file path with the file path substring. In this stage, the cow must repeat everything after users, so when they input a string, your program should print out the same string as the first line;
2. After the reply, print the cow picture as in the example section (16 characters wide). As you remember from the first stage, the lines on the picture should have the same length and are formatted with whitespaces.

**Example 1:**

```
Input the file path:
> C:\Users\ASCII_Cow\MooFolder\MooFile.txt
C:\Users\ASCII_Cow\MooFolder\MooFile.txt
            ^__^
    _______/(oo)
/\/(       /(__)
   | w----||
   ||     ||
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input the file path:
> This is not a file path. Moo :)
This is not a file path. Moo :)
            ^__^
    _______/(oo)
/\/(       /(__)
   | w----||
   ||     ||
```

My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\ASCII_Cow\\MooFolder\\MooFile.txt";
        System.out.println("Input the file path: ");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileInput = reader.readLine();
        if (fileInput.equals(filepath)) {
            System.out.println(filepath);
            System.out.print(
                    "            ^__^\n" +
                            "    _______/(oo)\n" +
                            "/\\/(       /(__)\n" +
                            "   | w----||    \n" +
                            "   ||     ||    ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is not a file path. Moo :)");
            System.out.println(
                    "            ^__^\n" +
                            "    _______/(oo)\n" +
                            "/\\/(       /(__)\n" +
                            "   | w----||    \n" +
                            "   ||     ||    ");
        }

    }
}
```

Second test doesn't pass:
*Wrong answer in test #2 When the user entered any string, program should output exactly 9 non-empty lines, first one should contain user's input, other 5 ones should contain ascii cow's picture...*

**Test file source code:**

```
public class MirrorTest extends StageTest {

  String[] test_data = {
          " ","test","C:\\Users\\Examples\\test.txt","/home/username/test.txt"
  };

  @DynamicTest(data = "test_data")
  CheckResult testSolution(String input) {
    TestedProgram pr = new TestedProgram();
    String output = pr.start().strip().toLowerCase();
    String[] strings = output.strip().split("\n");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strings));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
    if(list.size()!=1 || !list.get(0).contains("file path")){
      throw new WrongAnswer("When the program just started, output should contain exactly 1 non-empty line " +
              "with \"file path\" substring");
    }
    output = pr.execute(input);
    strings = output.split("\n");
    list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strings));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
    if(list.size()!=6 || !list.get(0).contains(input)){
      throw new WrongAnswer("When the user entered any string, program should output exactly 9 non-empty" +
              " lines, first one should contain user's input, other 5 ones should contain ascii cow's picture");
    }
    List<String> correctList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            "            ^__^",
            "    _______/(oo)",
            "/\\/(       /(__)",
            "   | w----||    ",
            "   ||     ||    "));
    for (int i=1;i<list.size();i++){
      if(!list.get(i).equals(correctList.get(i-1))){
        throw new WrongAnswer("All the printed lines in ascii cow's picture should be equal to lines in the " +
                " example. Make sure, that you've not ignored whitespaces at the beginning and at the end of each line");
      }
    }
    if(!pr.isFinished()){
      throw new WrongAnswer("Program should finish after outputting the picture");
    }
    return CheckResult.correct();
  }
}
```

**The issue is I tried various options of printing 9th line - `"\n"`, `println()`, `println("")` and so on.
If I run the program manually - I have 9 lines, if I check with tests 9th line doesn't appear, only 8 lines.**

Console output after test:

```
Input the file path: 
> test
This is not a file path. Moo :)
            ^__^
    _______/(oo)
/\/(       /(__)
   | w----||    
   ||     ||
```

Comment: Are you supposed to print out whatever file path the user happens to enter, rather than always print the examples *C:\Users\ASCII_Cow\MooFolder\MooFile.txt* and *This is not a file path. Moo :)*?

Comment: I should always print a cow, just with different answers
Like: This is not a file path. Moo :) if incorect or FilePath + cow if correct